# Make a new element appear on certain time

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, time

I have a task to add banner on website that appears when the live broadcasting of the event starts. It has fixed time, for example every saturday 14:00 GMT+2. How can i do this, can't find any tutorials or tools.

I understand that i need to have a javascript tool which adds html element like div on excact set time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to periodically check for the event.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    if(date.getDay() == 6 && date.getHours() == 14 && date.getMinutes() == 0){
        var container = document.getElementById("#container");
        container.innerHTML = "<div>BROADCASTED EVENT</div>";
    }
},1000*60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var showTime = Date.parse('Thu Mar 26 2015 09:11:19 GMT+0100');

function timerfun() {
var curTime = new Date();
var done = false;
    if (curTime > showTime) {
            done = true; 
            alert("Hello I'm awful banner!");
    }

    if (!done) {
        setTimeout(timerfun, 1000);
    }
}

setTimeout(timerfun, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment still cause of not enough rep. I want to add to Aditya's answer:

The nubmers below:
1000 represents 1000ms which is 1 second, times 60 means the function will check the time every minute, if you want to change how many times the function performs each check.

The function will continue endlessly, if you want to stop it, use clearInterval()

Answer (score 0):

If you do this with JavaScript the banner appearance will depend on the user's time. If the user has set the time wrong on his device, then you have a problem. The right way to do it is to use a backend language, like PHP or Java, store the apperance date in the database and before you send the banner data to the client, check if the stored date is the same with the current date.
For example:

```
 <?php
   banner = new Banner();
   (if banner.showTime === date()) {
     echo '<img src="' + banner.src + '" />
   }

 ?>
```